# Draw route on osmdroid map with osmbonuspack library

Tags: android, gson, geojson, osmdroid

I have created osmdroid map view on which I display custom WMS, that's works. Next I need draw dinamically on this map route between 2 points which I get from custom service in GeoJSON format. GeoJSON looks like this: http://pastebin.com/GJWYNkAq

Calling service over OkHttp Client:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:7915/GeoService.svc/GetRoute?" + "source=" + encodedSourceAddress + "&target=" + encodedTargetAddress)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful())
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                String result = response.body().string();
                Log.d("RESULT", result);
                viewRoute(result); //json is received ok, I debugged it

            }

        });
```

I used for this Osmbonuspack library in this method:

```
public void viewRoute(String geoJson) {
    KmlDocument kmlDocument = new KmlDocument();
    kmlDocument.parseGeoJSON(geoJson); //application is crashed here
    FolderOverlay myOverLay = (FolderOverlay) kmlDocument.mKmlRoot.buildOverlay(map, null, null, kmlDocument);
    map.getOverlays().add(myOverLay);
    map.invalidate();
}
```

When I run app, after launching is crashed with this error:

> 03-09 13:01:51.521 3968-3992/bachelor.vsb.martin.osmdroidclient E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
>   Process: bachelor.vsb.martin.osmdroidclient, PID: 3968
>                                                                                     java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonNull cannot be cast
>   to com.google.gson.JsonObject
>                                                                                         at com.google.gson.JsonObject.getAsJsonObject(JsonObject.java:191)
>                                                                                         at
>   org.osmdroid.bonuspack.kml.KmlPlacemark.(KmlPlacemark.java:89)
>                                                                                         at
>   org.osmdroid.bonuspack.kml.KmlFeature.parseGeoJSON(KmlFeature.java:237)
>                                                                                         at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.kml.KmlFolder.(KmlFolder.java:62)
>                                                                                         at
>   org.osmdroid.bonuspack.kml.KmlFeature.parseGeoJSON(KmlFeature.java:235)
>                                                                                         at
>   org.osmdroid.bonuspack.kml.KmlDocument.parseGeoJSON(KmlDocument.java:1097)
>                                                                                         at
>   org.osmdroid.bonuspack.kml.KmlDocument.parseGeoJSON(KmlDocument.java:1112)
>                                                                                         at
>   bachelor.vsb.martin.osmdroidclient.MainActivity.viewRoute(MainActivity.java:137)
>                                                                                         at
>   bachelor.vsb.martin.osmdroidclient.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:127)
>                                                                                         at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
>                                                                                         at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
>                                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

I am using osmdroid 5.6.4, and osmbonuspack 6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in that library. The [current](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/ecd64a595f48ecf0412daad40c1ef256670ef427/OSMBonusPack/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/kml/KmlPlacemark.java#L89) implementation at the master branch is implemented like this:

```java
89: JsonObject geometry = json.getAsJsonObject("geometry");
90: if (geometry != null) {
```

Yes, `getAsJsonObject` can return `null` for not existing keys, but Gson uses `JsonNull` as the `null` value marker (and it makes sense) if the given JSON path value is known to be `null`. The only path that has the `null` in your JSON is `$.features[6].geometry`, so I'm assuming this one is the only cause. What you can do here is raising a new issue at their GitHub issues desk to add an appropriate `JsonNull` check in order not to fail at the type cast. A simulated case:

```java
final JsonObject geometry = (JsonObject) geoJsonObject.getAsJsonObject()
        .get("features")
        .getAsJsonArray()
        .get(6)
        .getAsJsonObject()
        .get("geometry"); // actually JsonNull for $.features[6].geometry
```

What you can do here so far is:

- Either remove the that path from the tree (I didn't analyze if that library can work with empty/incomplete `geometry` `JsonPath` elements, so probably just replacing that path value won't work).
- Or remove the entire 7th `feature` object (this probably would be more appropriate, but it would cause some data loss).

An example for the first option:

```java
final JsonObject geoJsonObject = gson.fromJson(geoJson, JsonObject.class);
fixGeoJsonObject(geoJsonObject);
kmlDocument.parseGeoJSON(geoJsonObject); // passing the "fixed" object
```

where `fixGeoJsonObject` is as follows:

```java
private static void fixGeoJsonObject(final JsonObject geoJsonObject) {
    final JsonArray features = geoJsonObject
            .get("features")
            .getAsJsonArray();
    final int length = features.size();
    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        final JsonObject feature = features.get(i)
                .getAsJsonObject();
        final JsonElement geometry = feature.get("geometry");
        if ( geometry.isJsonNull() ) {
            feature.remove("geometry"); // losing some data...
        }
    }
}
```

or for the second option:

```java
private static void fixGeoJsonObject(final JsonObject geoJsonObject) {
    final JsonArray features = geoJsonObject
            .get("features")
            .getAsJsonArray();
    for ( int i = 0; i < features.size(); i++ ) {
        final JsonObject feature = features.get(i)
                .getAsJsonObject();
        final JsonElement geometry = feature.get("geometry");
        if ( geometry.isJsonNull() ) {
            features.remove(i); // losing even more data...
        }
    }
}
```

This should fix the `ClassCastException` you're getting, but I have no clue how it would affect the library you're using.

#### Edit 1:

- Bug report: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/issues/282
- Bug fix: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/commit/2cb85bca5f1625e9396504e2baa39decd2787d2a

Comment: Yes ,you have right :) last item of GeoJSON is final element of route from pgr dijsktra, and has null geometry and -1 id of edge. After running your function works :)

Comment: @DenisStephanov No problem. It would be nice if you'd create an issue on their GitHub issues list to process `JsonNull` properly. After that you could easily remove the fix method that's actually destructive per se (suppose you're passing a JSON object, not a string since regular parsing hits performance).

Comment: @DenisStephanov The development team has confirmed the bug and released the patch: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/commit/2cb85bca5f1625e9396504e2baa39decd2787d2a . Congratulations for the quickly fixed bug report. :)